# How to remove empty item from List<string>?

Tags: c#

I have been trying for some time to remove empty items from List, what I mean:

```
list1.Add("1")
list1.Add("")
list1.Add("  ")
list1.Add("2")
```

OutPut:
1
2

Here is what I tried:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list.Add("1  3");
list.Add("     ");
list.Add("        ");
list.Add("2");
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
{
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(list[i], @"\s");
    foreach(Match m in mc)
    {
        if (!list.Contains(m.ToString()))
            list1.Add(m.ToString());
    }
}
```

I new to programming so I sorry if this question is bad

Answer (score 8):

```
list.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
```

Although be careful, `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` checks for more than just spaces. For the full list check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` doesn't "remove" anything

Comment: @spender reworded

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this, you can use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method.

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
    {
        list1.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Another way to do it with LINQ:

```
var filteredList = list.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: oh, and is it possible to do something like this? if(list[i].contains(Regex.Matches(something)))?

Comment: @Daniel - Sure you could use regex, but general rule of thumb should be to avoid it if you can (and I mean *very* general rule, it obviously has it's uses). Especially with something so simple it's just not necessary. I'd also assume it doesn't perform as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()

```
        List<string> listWithEmtyAndNullElements = new List<string>
            { "",
              " ",
              "Hi",
              "Stack     ",
              "    Overflow",
                null
            };

        List<string> onlyStringList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listWithEmtyAndNullElements.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(listWithEmtyAndNullElements[i]))
            {
                onlyStringList.Add(listWithEmtyAndNullElements[i]);
            }
         }
```